# Microsoft dynamics crm 2011 adapter

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to synchronize data between two CRM organizations. I installed connector and configured adapter for Account entity. So far good.. But the problem is.

I would like to do Initial data synchronization from my Source CRM 2011 to Destination CRM 2011. How can I do that?

I am in dire need of it. It wasted my two days still didn't get the answer.

Thanks in advance for the response.
Regards,
Pavan.G

Comment: what about Data Import? Can't you setup it by initial data Import as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/23/transferring-data-from-one-crm-organization-to-other-organization.aspx

Comment: No, My client requirement is to use CRM adapter only. Now. I would like to know how to start initial data sync process.

Answer (score 0):

- Write console application that executes update on records which should by synchronized
- run above application against source
- synchronization connector should pick up updates and  send records to destination

There might be some implications with ModifiedBy and ModifiedOn fields (as they would be updated by console app). Depends if you care about them.

Comment: I want to use only CRM 2011 Connector. Tell me a way how the initial data synchronization works?

Comment: Steps to Follow:

1. First We need to configure the connector
2. Then assign "Dynamic Integration" role to the user(s)
3. Select “yes” for “Integration User Mode”.
4. In the CRM Adapter, create the map between required entities.
5. Then Activate the Map which the user wants to synchronize.
6. Save the settings.

Then it will start synchronizing the data.